# Flutter chrash in Android 12l with "No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener"

Tags: android, flutter

I must upgrade a project written in flutter to compileSdkVersion 33
Since i upgraded, the app crahes at least in simulator.
A new flutter project whith compileSdkVersion 33 make no problems, but i can't find the differences in gradle.build files or android manifest.

Any ideas?

Flutter Version:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.5, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Error:

```
D/FlutterLocationService(13862): Binding to location service.
E/AndroidRuntime(13862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13862): Process: de.roegmbh.checkit, PID: 13862
E/AndroidRuntime(13862): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;Lj$/util/function/Consumer;)V in class Landroidx/window/extensions/layout/WindowLayoutComponent; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.window.extensions.layout.WindowLayoutComponent' appears in /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at androidx.window.layout.ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.registerLayoutChangeCallback(ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.kt:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerImpl.kt:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:212)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at androidx.window.java.layout.WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter$addListener$1$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter.kt:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(13862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: I solved it by copying step by step old android code in a new generated flutter project. At least I delete build folder at old project and copied the whole new android folder to existig project.Now I can start the old project and no errorany more.

Comment: I'm hitting this in production, any idea what you changed that fixed it? 
@KlausSzilvas

Answer (score 57):

Try adding the following dependencies in the android/app/build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
```

This is in Groovy. If you are using Kotlin, write add these dependencies with the appropriate syntax.

---

I faced this issue when I added [desugaring](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#gradle-setup) required for [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package. I was running an android emulator with the following configuration (android/app/build.gradle):

```
minSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```

My gradle version is 7.5.1, and my android gradle plugin version is 7.3.1. Therefore, I used desugar_jdk_libs version 1.2.2 to [support targetSdkVersion 33](https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
```

minSdkVersion is 22, so multidex is [enabled by default](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l).

Comment: This is a correct solution, worked for me.

Comment: if i knew where u live, i'd send you a cake

Comment: @Madushan Tell me about it, I've been banging my head against the wall on this all night

Comment: Adding the 2 lines worked for me as well. Very good job!

Comment: This solution is included in the official docs https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup

Comment: @sr9yar, you're right. But it wasn't in the docs when I posted this solution.

Comment: oh my god i love you !!!!!!!!!!! this is the SOLUTION IT WORKSSSSSSSS

Comment: nailed it, life saver man !!!!!!

Comment: For those wondering, this needs be added in the "dependencies" section at the top level.

Comment: Note that implementation are added in `dependencies` area like

`dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
}`

Answer (score 13):

### Root cause:

`FlutterView#onAttachedToWindow` use `androidx.window` WindowInfoTracker api to get device info

Once Phone System contains `/system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar`
There will call `WindowLayoutComponent.addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V`

If APP enable java 8+ api desuagr,

There will convert java 8+ api package from jave to j$
from java/util/function/Consumer to `j$/util/function/Consumer`

In app code, there will call
WindowLayoutComponent.addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;`Lj$/util/function/Consumer;`)V

But in /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar
The api is WindowLayoutComponent.addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;`Ljava/util/function/Consumer;`)V

So there will throw `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

### Solution:

androix.window has fixed this problem
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/d9a44f767d5d821200bcf9f0093c413a258c5351
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/d9a44f767d5d821200bcf9f0093c413a258c5351:window/window/src/main/java/androidx/window/layout/ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.kt;dlc=0a3d4b6fd89bc54e78ddab5a941972ee6546be2e

So change androidx.window:window version to `1.1.0-alpha04` can solve this problem