# Flutter Run show message "Lost connection to device." after run app in emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I had this old project I wanted to make some updates.
I start by updating the all packages
and migrating to null safety all goes good. and updated my flutter version to  3.7.4
but when run on emulator the logo come out but crash after that and this is run log  :

> `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Attaching Geolocator to activity D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Creating service. D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Binding to location service. D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Geolocator foreground service connected D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Initializing Geolocator services D/FlutterGeolocator( 6309): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1 Lost connection to device.`

note: working find on real device
anyone can help ?

expecting to work fine as will as the working in real device

i all ready try
flutter clean

---

I update the emulator and i have some more info about in run log
here its :

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √  Built
> build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Attaching Geolocator to activity
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Creating service.
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Binding to location service.
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Geolocator foreground service connected
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Initializing Geolocator services
> D/FlutterGeolocator(13885): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine
> count 1 E/AndroidRuntime(13885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885): Process: com.APPID, PID: 13885
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface
> method
> addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;Lj$/util/function/Consumer;)V
> in class Landroidx/window/extensions/layout/WindowLayoutComponent; or
> its super classes (declaration of
> 'androidx.window.extensions.layout.WindowLayoutComponent' appears in
> /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> androidx.window.layout.ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.registerLayoutChangeCallback(ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.kt:68)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerImpl.kt:52)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown
> Source:8) E/AndroidRuntime(13885):    at
> androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown
> Source:4) E/AndroidRuntime(13885):    at
> kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:212)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> androidx.window.java.layout.WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter$addListener$1$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter.kt:96)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) E/AndroidRuntime(13885):
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) E/AndroidRuntime(13885):
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> E/AndroidRuntime(13885):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) Lost
> connection to device.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that after updating the library ***flutter_local_notifications***
Add this tow lines

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
> implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
> ```

to the file *android/app/build.gradle* fix the Problem

answer found in
[Flutter chrash in Android 12l with "No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74163927/flutter-chrash-in-android-12l-with-no-interface-method-addwindowlayoutinfoliste)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).